# State changes, components re-render React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 countdowns.

`First` ticks 1 minute adds +1 to count  each time countdown restarts.

`Second` ticks 2 minutes adds +2 to count each time countdown restarts.

The second never reaches to 0, the first countdown after 1 minute resets (changing the state), and then both countdowns restart. Any way i can do this?

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
  seconds: 1000 * 60,
  seconds2: 2100 * 60,
  count: 0,
  exp: 0,
};

render(){
return(

<View>
   <TimerCountdown
     initialSecondsRemaining={this.state.seconds}
     onTimeElapsed={() => this.setState({seconds: 1500 * 60, count: this.state.count+1, exp: this.state.exp+1})}
     allowFontScaling={true}
     style={styles.clock}
   />

   <TimerCountdown
     initialSecondsRemaining={this.state.seconds2}
     onTimeElapsed={() => this.setState({seconds2: 2000 * 60, count: this.state.count+2, exp: this.state.exp+2})}
     allowFontScaling={true}
     style={styles.clock}
   />
</View>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is: state changes -> react rerenders -> timer restarts
to solve this define the timer in separate class as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import TimerCountdown from 'react-native-timer-countdown';


class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
        this.state = {
        seconds: this.props.seconds,
      };
    }
  render(){
    return (
      <TimerCountdown
        initialSecondsRemaining={this.state.seconds}
        onTimeElapsed={() => {
          this.setState({seconds: this.props.seconds});
          this.props.onTimeElapsed();
        }}
        allowFontScaling={true}
      />
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    seconds: 1000 * 60,
    seconds2: 2100 * 60,
    count: 0,
    exp: 0,
  };
  render() {
    return (<View>

      <Timer 
        seconds={this.state.seconds}
        onTimeElapsed={() => this.setState({seconds: 1500 * 60, count: this.state.count+1, exp: this.state.exp+1})}
      />
      <Timer 
        seconds={this.state.seconds2}
        onTimeElapsed={() => this.setState({seconds2: 2000 * 60, count: this.state.count+2, exp: this.state.exp+2})}
      />
    </View>);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `this.setState({seconds: this.props.seconds});` will trigger the state, and then everything re-renders. i get it to work without the count, but i need to add + to count everytime countdown gets to 0.